# actionbar search lower case is not working for snippet on addMarker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to locate the marker geo points by searching through the snippet. The snippet is where the Plate no. I have one problem I can't search for any other Plate No.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivityLocation
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
        SearchView.OnSuggestionListener {



     @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            for(Marker m : list) {
                if(m.getSnippet().toLowerCase().equals(query)) {
mMapFragment.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(m.getPosition(), 9.0f));
                    break; // stop the loop
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

On Another Class I added an arraylist that will hold the marker. What it'll do is to put all the markers on this list and retrieve back later.

```
public static List<Marker> list;

public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                // success response
                if (response.body().isJsonArray()) {
                    JsonArray objectWhichYouNeed = response.body().getAsJsonArray();
                    System.out.println(objectWhichYouNeed + " Object");
                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getAsJsonArray().size(); i++) {
                    JsonElement je = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                    JsonObject jo = je.getAsJsonObject();

                    String plate_n = jo.get("plate_num").toString();
                    String plate_nString = plate_n;
                    plate_nString = plate_nString.replace("\"", "");
                    String plate_num = String.valueOf(plate_nString);

                    String gps_num = jo.get("gps_num").toString();
                    String location = jo.get("location").toString();
                    String date = jo.get("date").toString();
                    String time = jo.get("time").toString();

                    String lati = jo.get("lat").toString();
                    String latiString = lati;
                    latiString = latiString.replace("\"", "");
                    String lat = String.valueOf(latiString);

                    String longi = jo.get("lng").toString();
                    String longiString = longi;
                    longiString = longiString.replace("\"", "");
                    String lng = String.valueOf(longiString);

                    String engine = jo.get("engine").toString();
                    String remarks = jo.get("remarks").toString();

                    if (lat != null && !lat.equals("null")
                            && (lng != null && !lng.equals("null")
                            || (lat != "" && lat != "")
                            && lng != "") && (lng != "")) {

                        Double d = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                        Double d2 = Double.parseDouble(lng);

                        MarkerOptions opts = createMarker(d, d2, plate_num);
                        Marker m = mMapFragment.addMarker(opts);
                        list.add(m);
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't you `return true` instead of `break`? Not sure if that fixes it, but you should log `m.getSnippet()` to see if the value is what you typed

Comment: Let me try, however it was a condition.. Right?

Comment: Hi, cricket_007. I am still getting the same value of m.getSnippet() /:

Comment: How do you get an error? You already have that code... `if(m.getSnippet().toLowerCase()`

Comment: Hi cricket_007, I am not getting an error However on for loop I am still getting the same value of m.getSnippet() /: