# How do you add addMarker on GoogleMap on Arraylist correctly

Tags: java, android, arraylist, google-maps-android-api-2

I am having a problem on how to add the addMarker on Arraylist. While I am using createMarker on my for loop to add values.

```
MainActivity extends BaseActivityLocation
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
        SearchView.OnSuggestionListener {

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    for(Marker m : list) {
        System.out.println(list+m.getSnippet() + m.getTitle() + m.getPosition() + " snippet");
        if(m.getSnippet().toLowerCase().equals(query)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You searched for: " + query , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mMapFragment.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(m.getPosition(), 9.0f));
            break; // stop the loop
        }
    }
    return false;
}

   public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
        // success response
        if (response.body().isJsonArray()) {
            JsonArray objectWhichYouNeed = response.body().getAsJsonArray();
            System.out.println(objectWhichYouNeed + " Object");

            for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getAsJsonArray().size(); i++) {
                JsonElement plate_num_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                JsonObject plate_num_obj = plate_num_array.getAsJsonObject();
                String plate_n = plate_num_obj.get("plate_num").toString();
                String plate_nString = plate_n;
                plate_nString = plate_nString.replace("\"", "");
                String plate_num = String.valueOf(plate_nString);

                JsonElement lat_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                JsonObject lat_obj = lat_array.getAsJsonObject();
                String lati = lat_obj.get("lat").toString();
                String latiString = lati;
                latiString = latiString.replace("\"", "");
                String lat = String.valueOf(latiString);

                JsonElement lng_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                JsonObject lng_obj = lng_array.getAsJsonObject();
                String longi = lng_obj.get("lng").toString();
                String longiString = longi;
                longiString = longiString.replace("\"", "");
                String lng = String.valueOf(longiString);

                createMarker(d, d2, plate_num);
            }
```

Problem here is when createMarker is called the marker will just replace its value on the Arraylist. What I want is to add the marker in arraylist like [0,0,0,0].. How do I achieve that?

```
 public MarkerOptions createMarker(Double latitude, final Double longitude, String Plate_num) {
    BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.print(list + " Snippp");

   /*  mMapFragment.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .title("Plate No.")
            .snippet(Plate_num)
            .icon(image));*/

    mMapFragment.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
        }
    });

    mMapFragment.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 9.0f));

    mMapFragment.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            vm = new VehicleMap();

            vm.setSnippet(marker.getSnippet());
            vm.setPlate_num(marker.getSnippet());

            latitudeG = marker.getPosition().latitude;
            longitudeG = marker.getPosition().longitude;

            marker.showInfoWindow();

            BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new BottomSheetModalFragment(activity);
            bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());

            return true;
        }
    });

    return new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .title("Plate No.")
            .snippet(Plate_num)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

}
```

Comment: Your JSON parsing looks very complicated. You called `response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i)` three times... That's the *exact same*  object, so you only need to call that once.

Comment: Thank you for seeing that. @Cricket_007 Usually happens when on rush

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what `.replace("\"", "");` is trying to do, but if you have converted a JSON object to a String, then you'll get backslashes in the data, but they aren't actually there. They are only displayed when you look at the data

Comment: it removes the value that enclose with ""

Comment: Yes, but those are JSON strings that have been escaped, which means you are doing some extra encoding somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not overwriting a value, it's replacing the entire list.

Don't make a new list. Have the method create and return.

```
public MarkerOptions createMarker(Double latitude, final Double longitude, String Plate_num) {

    // list = new ArrayList<>(); // Don't do this

    BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus);

   return new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .title("Plate No.")
            .snippet(Plate_num)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
}
```

...

```
onResponse( ... ) {
    ...
    String lng = String.valueOf(longiString);

    MarkerOptions opts = createMarker(d, d2, plate_num);
    Marker m = mMapFragment.addMarker(opts);
    list.add(m);
}
```

Comment: Hi crickket_007, where do I put these?

`MarkerOptions opts = createMarker(d, d2, plate_num);
Marker m = mMapFragment.addMarker(opts);
list.add(m);`

Comment: At the end of `onResponse` where you already have `createMarker`?

Comment: can you debug why I am still getting the same Plate No. `https://pastebin.com/gB0ASNRx`

Comment: Not without a [mcve], no. Perhaps you can read. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506/why-does-my-arraylist-contain-n-copies-of-the-last-item-added-to-the-list

Comment: No worries. Do you have idea on how I can use the `List<Marker> list` on another class that I'll be using on the pastebin code? I read that `If the objects in your list store data in static fields, each object in your list will appear to be the same `

Comment: Depends on the class. If an Activity, then `MarkerOptions implements Parcelable`, so you can use `Intent#putParcelableArrayListExtra` to pass data between Fragments and Activities. Note, that is for the **MakerOptions**, not the Marker objects

Comment: All your markers have the same `title("Plate No.")`, only the snippet is different. Or all your JSON is the same

Comment: I've updated above code it was using `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: I would store the MarkerOptions in the List. Then in `onMapReady` of your Fragment, you can add all the Markers.

Comment: Hi cricket_007, pls. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580110/actionbar-search-lower-case-is-not-working-for-snippet-on-addmarker What I want using `onQueryTextSubmit` is to search for a geolocation

Comment: the snippet is place differently. It was enclosed in the for-loop below `response.body()`