# How to add multiple markers with an array of geopoints on android?

Tags: java, android

I need to add a list of geopoints as markers on top of my custom OSM map in my android device, the below code is a sample for showing up one marker.

```
GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(48.13, -1.63);
Marker startMarker = new Marker(map);
startMarker.setPosition(startPoint);
startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
map.getOverlays().add(startMarker);
```

Comment: Have you considered using `ArrayList` and storing it in Database using a `Cursor`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953792/search-marker-from-edit-text-in-maps-fragment-android/45954165?noredirect=1#comment78881485_45954165

Comment: @Mandy8055 i tried using an array but only the last index worked, can u send a sample implementation by using arraylist without cursor?